Samsung Galaxy A12 won't show OEM unlocking option
I have a Samsung Galaxy A12. In the Developer options, OEM unlocking cannot be found.
I have tried various guides and they all boil down to change the date and reboot the system. I have tried this multiple times.
Do I really need to wait 7 days to get access to OEM unlock? Is there a way to change this setting via the Android shell or ADB?

Where does the 7 day come from? Is this a locked phone from a Telco?

AFAIK, the 7-day waiting is for the Xiaomi device, not Samsung, but I could be wrong.

@rohitgupta no, i think i just followed fake guides.

Look at phone info for software information, and click on Android security patch levels. If you are redirected to the Android browser, everything is fine.
If that doesn't work, it could well be that you have nasty spyware. Root and recovery hard reset everything is just a waste of time, sideload OTG, just like that.
